# Jquery event fire with bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap tab in my view

```
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <ul id="MyTabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#details" id="TabDetailsLink">Personal
                Details</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" id="Tab1">T1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" id="Tab2">T2</a></li>

        </ul>

and i use jquery for catch the event
$(".MyTabs li").click(function (e) {
    alert(2);
});
```

My expectation is to get the alert whenever I change the tabs. But the event is not getting fired. Mine is an ASP.NET MVC 4 web api application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is wrong ! `MyTabs` is the Id. So use it with `#` prefix

This should work.

```
$("#MyTabs li").click(function (e) {
    e.prevelitDefault(); 
    alert(2);
});
```

Or you can use your existing jQuery selector if you add this class to yuur ul element.

```
<ul id="MyTabs" class="MyTabs nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
```

**When using Id as your jQuery selector**, use `#` prefix ( Ex : `$("#myElementUniqueID")`)

**When using css class as your jQuery selector**, use `.` prefix ( Ex : `$(".myCssClss")` )

Comment: You are right i was using the class selector instead of id selector. It worked if i change to #

Comment: Yep..thanks for  the detailed explanation. which is the best way to use id selector or class selector?

Comment: IF you are targeting only one element, Use Id selector.(**Id's should be Unique**) If you have multiple items, Use css class. (Ex :If you want to attach some common behavior to a bunch of a tags)

Comment: I will use id selector